# Ciclo while para generar archivos de distintos nombres

Tags: java, android, android-studio, while

Estoy intentando generar muchos archivos en un intervalo de 2 segundos(en realidad se hará cada 5 minutos pero para saber si funciona 2 segundos son más que suficientes) , pero que estos no se sobrescriban entre si(dado que llevan datos de un sensor y se irán subiendo a la nube), el tema es que no logro generar el cambio de nombre(se que es un ciclo while pero no se como plantearlo).
La idea es que los archivos sigan una serie: 1.csv , 2.csv , 3.csv , 4.csv

Si existe otra forma sin while de generar estos archivos también me sirve.

```
                        int n=1;
                        File f = new File(String.valueOf(n));

                        while (true){

                            long t= System.currentTimeMillis();
                            long end = t+2000;



                            while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end){

                                while(f.exists()){
                                    return n=n+1;
                                }

                                fos = openFileOutput(String.valueOf(n), MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

he modificado un poco de tu código para que genere la cantidad de archivos que tu desees ya que con tiempo es bastante exagerada la cantidad. Sin embargo, te he dejado comentado el codigo

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class STOF3 {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
        STOF3 s = new STOF3();
        s.generarArchivos(1);
    }

    public void generarArchivos(int segundos) throws FileNotFoundException {
        FileOutputStream fos;
        int n = 1;
        long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long end = t+segundos*1000;

        while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end){

            File f = new File(String.valueOf(n));
            fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
            n++;
        }
    }
}
```